# Parsing and concatenating value within XML tag

Tags: java

I currently have a logic for parsing XML file and mapping xml tag with its values to the List. I have couple of tags which have "-" characters which break further mapping. How can I remove them and concatenate the strings inside XML tag?

Here is the example of XML which I would like to cancatenate

`<tag-with-dash>` and I need to have `<tagWithDash>` after parsing. CamelCase preferrably, but low case if fine too.

here is the logic for getting xml tag key:

```
protected String getXMLType(String parsingMessage) {
        int start = parsingMessage.indexOf('<', 1) + 1;
        int end = parsingMessage.indexOf('>', start);
        String substring = parsingMessage.substring(start, end);
        if (REGEX_TAG.matcher(substring).matches()) {
            return substring;
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid tag '{}' using regex pattern '{}'.", substring, REGEX_TAG.pattern());
            return "INVALID";
        }
    }
```

Regex pattern:

```
REGEX_TAG = "^[/A-Z0-9_-]+$"
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What does your parsingMessage contains?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to convert the dashed string to camel case

```
public static String toCamelCase(String s) {    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean caps = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            caps = true;
        } else {
            if (caps) sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            else sb.append(c);
            caps = false;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Use it like this

```
protected String getXMLType(String parsingMessage) {
    int start = parsingMessage.indexOf('<', 1) + 1;
    int end = parsingMessage.indexOf('>', start);
    String substring = parsingMessage.substring(start, end);
    if (REGEX_TAG.matcher(substring).matches()) {
        return toCamelCase(substring);
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid tag '{}' using regex pattern '{}'.", substring, REGEX_TAG.pattern());
        return "INVALID";
    }
}
```